# TotalResults count doesn't match with the actual results returned in YouTube v3 search API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using youtube v3 search API. We are getting mismatch in the "totalResults" count and the list of items returned in the response.items field. I am requesting 50 videos in the request. Response returned shows totalResults count as 65 but the response payload has only 3 videos.

API : [www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/list](http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/list)

Request Payload

```
{key=API_KEY, maxResults=50, order=date, part=snippet, publishedAfter=2017-03-20T23:59:59.999-04:00, publishedBefore=2017-04-19T23:59:59.001-04:00, q=( ( "Wood Mackenzie" OR "Wood Mac" OR Woodmac OR @woodmackenzie ) AND NOT (fleetwood OR "fleet wood" OR 9WoodMac ) )  , type=video}
```

Response Payload

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/HTW4WQODZeERIv51VrRfOhir8dg\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 65,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/lnNNrToZHGTehIEJ6bvEx5RZMo4\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "obzlB21t904"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-04-14T11:38:08.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC60Sa1LQjgy_a-K8ThN4eQw",
    "title": "Fleet wood mac Live at Leeds",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/obzlB21t904/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/obzlB21t904/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/obzlB21t904/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "KEVIN MARSHALL",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/uYuuTAL3vtnFI1WOYjth0cso2Xo\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "gHAn0SbwKMg"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-04-06T22:17:31.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC3_MxBSSbmGznoSTgoBQ7_w",
    "title": "Beat Club: British Invasion 60's, Pt-2; Animals-Move-Fleet Wood Mac-J.Mayall-Who-Pacemakers-Kinks",
    "description": "Eric Burdon & Animals: C.C. Rider 0:01 The Move: Wild Tiger Woman 3:55 Fleet Wood Mac: Dragonfly 6:26 John Mayall: My Pretty Girl 9:47 Thunderclap ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gHAn0SbwKMg/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gHAn0SbwKMg/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gHAn0SbwKMg/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "ROCK&POPS1_koba",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/tapelxOG4Q3gZRJCR2qaVdt-ZO8\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "5GvLbFBdcF4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-04-02T04:48:47.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC6fn383TI1HVDYW4dSEIogQ",
    "title": "\"Dreams\" by fleet wood mac (vocal cover)",
    "description": "I do not own this song. I do not make a profit off of this song. It belongs to the person(s) who wrote it. Please subscribe and comment below any suggestions?!",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5GvLbFBdcF4/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5GvLbFBdcF4/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5GvLbFBdcF4/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Musikallitee",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) itself, the `totalResults` is:

> **integer**
>
> The total number of results in the result set.Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value. In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.
>
> You should not use this value to create pagination links. Instead, use the **nextPageToken** and **prevPageToken** property values to determine whether to show pagination links.

The value is only an approximation/estimate, but not the exact value for the total number of `items` returned. I've tested the API with the same details as yours and the value tends to change from `63`, to `64`, and `65`.

With all that said, there is nothing wrong in your code. It's just the expected behavior. Unfortunately, it is not stated anywhere as to where the value of `totalResults` is based on or where it is best used. It's best to proceed with an implementation that doesn't rely on this parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really appreciate.